# django - Searchview from two models using chain

Tags: django, chain

I want to display search results combing two models. I am getting the search result from one model and not from the other. The field from the second model, datafile is not displayed. Not sure what I am missing.

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
  template_name = 'searchresults.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        meta_list = Metadataform.objects.filter(
            Q(id__icontains=query) | Q(Authors_Name__icontains=query) | Q(Affliations__icontains=query) | Q(Methods__icontains=query) | Q(Instruments__icontains=query) | Q(Software__icontains=query)| Q(Models__icontains=query)| Q(Device__icontains=query)
        )

        dataset_list = uploadmeta.objects.filter(Q(datafile__icontains=query)
        )

        object_list = chain(meta_list, dataset_list)
        return object_list
```

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Meta ID</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Download</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% if object_list %}

          {% for a in object_list %}


            <tr>
                <td>{{ a.Authors_Name }}</td>
                <td>  {{ a.datafile }} </td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}

          {% else %}
          {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please check that the result of `dataset_list = uploadmeta.objects.filter(Q(datafile__icontains=query))` is returning what you expect it to return. It could be a data issue.

Comment: Thanks, there is data in that query that does not show up

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using the `itertools.chain` function to join multiple querysets together.

2 things to try:

1. Check the result of `dataset_list = uploadmeta.objects.filter(Q(datafile__icontains=query))` it could be there are actually no results being found as a result of this query. Which would mean that no results are going to be present (check the data).
2. Try removing the `model` class attribute. Try removing the model definition in `SearchResultsView`.

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'searchresults.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        meta_list = Metadataform.objects.filter(
            Q(id__icontains=query) | Q(Authors_Name__icontains=query) | Q(Affliations__icontains=query) | Q(Methods__icontains=query) | Q(Instruments__icontains=query) | Q(Software__icontains=query)| Q(Models__icontains=query)| Q(Device__icontains=query)
        )

        dataset_list = uploadmeta.objects.filter(Q(datafile__icontains=query)
        )

        object_list = list(chain(meta_list, dataset_list))
        return object_list
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both your points. still, i don't see the data that is there and has to be fetched. would it be an issue if that datafile is a foreignkey?

Comment: I basically want to fetch fields from two tables joining them... like this sql                              SELECT "SSDatabase_metadataform".*, "SSDatabase_uploadmeta"."datafile" from "SSDatabase_metadataform" INNER JOIN "SSDatabase_uploadmeta" ON "SSDatabase_metadataform"."id" = "SSDatabase_uploadmeta"."path_id" order by "id"'

Comment: Are you sure the data exists?

Comment: Matt Seymour:Could you please help me with this. The search works fine and shows data from one model but does not fetch the correcponding data from the second model. Could you tell me what i am missing? The code is the same, i have not changed anything